# How to efficiently verify existence of large volume of files using JCIFS library?

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I have a process that reads database to gather the server and path information of about 200,000 files (and growing). I used JCIFS library to check if the file exists on the designated location one at a time using something like:

```
SmbFile file = new SmbFile(fullPath, getNtlmPasswordAuthentication());
if(file.exists()) {
     return true;
}
```

It takes couple hours to complete the process. I'm trying to find a way to speed up the process. The files needed to be verified spread over 40 directories. Each directory can contain couple thousand of files. The *SmbFile* [API](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/) has a *listFiles()* function that allows me to open a directory and get back an array of *SmbFile* in that folder. I wonder if I'm on the right track and if anyone has better idea. Thanks!

Comment: Can you run code on the remote host?

Comment: Not really. The requirement is to create a UI for people who need to use the tool on a web environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely you should use listFiles(). If I'm understanding things correctly, your approach results in a request-per-file, and listFiles() will give you a request-per-directory - I'd expect speed up of x1000 or so

Comment: Thanks! It's really fast now!